# Disable chrome auto refresh bug

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, malware

When chrome starts, whenever I open a new tab and start surfing, the tab in which I have the focus gets refreshed to Google.com. Every time I change, after 1 or 2 secs it gets back to Google.com. When I change the tab, the same behaviour starts occurring in this tab.
When I go to the configuration pages, the same happens, I can't change the config since the tab gets reloaded to google.
I tryed starting chrome without extensions from the console and I still have the same issue.

Any idea?

Comment: Disable all Chrome extensions and, if it helps, then try enabling them one by one before you encounter the problematic extension.

Comment: I've already tried that!

Comment: Ok, sorry. Only if you could put `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default` folder into an archive and upload it somewhere so that I could take a look, but it could compromise you privacy. However, if you clear all privacy data by doing Ctrl+Shift+Delete, checking all the checkboxes, clicking "Clear browsing data" button, then exporting all your bookmarks and then deleting all the bookmarks from Chrome, you could consider uploading the `Default` folder to let me or other people help you. At least now you know which folder to delete if you decide to re-install Chrome.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to resolve this inside Chrome Version 48.0 (Running on Windows 7) by performing the following steps.

1. Open the Chrome browser and navigate to `chrome://flags`
2. Search on the page for "Enable tab discarding"
3. Set this flag to "Disabled"
4. Restart Chrome.